# Tartan shader - understanding the math, I stumbled upon

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes

I'm looking into doing some anime shading as many are right now.

I made a tartan shader following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yonXoF6obyc

I adapted the node setup, since I don't use lights or normals.

[image: 01]

Most everything is controlled by individual UV maps.
[image: 02]

These sections mostly follows the tutorial.
[image: 03]

My biggest question is about the math node, I use as a factor.
The tutorial just multiplies them together, but I wanted two things:

a) I never use hard edges. I always use color ramps with ease.
b) I use clean colors with shadows produced solely by the shader itself.

I managed to somehow overlap the two cleanly.
"Cleanly" as in they overwrite each other
and are not blended using alpha channels.

[image: 04]
[image: 05]

I just have no idea, how the math works on the last "greater than" node.
Can somebody help me understand, what is happening here?

I hope, I was able to explain myself properly :)

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The math on the greater than node works like this, if the top value is higher than the threshold it will give an output. This is likely why your output appears sharp instead of smooth. [Here's some more information about the math nodes.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math.html)